# Heroku Rails 4 / Ruby 2.0.0 Deploy Fail, Production Database is not connectable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `new'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:513:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `included'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `include'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `taggable_on'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:39:in `acts_as_taggable_on'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:15:in `acts_as_taggable'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/app/models/op.rb:37:in `<class:Op>'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/app/models/op.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:188:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:248:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0.rc4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_5h4sx2s7f96x/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       NOTICE: Please install 'typhoeus' gem for optimal performance.
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:bestofama.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I'm not sure if it's a database connections issue?

https://github.com/andey/bestofama/blob/master/config/database.yml

But it thought heroku overwrites the production config anyways?

Might be an issue with acts as taggable. But why? The app runs fine locally.
BTW: this is the first time I'm trying to deploy a ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4 upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails is trying to connect to your database during the asset compilation phase. This can be disabled by:

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

You can let heroku have access to the environment during asset compilation

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: Rails 4 defaults to not initializing on precompile, so i'm curious why this was needed. If this code was in the original Rails 3 app it wouldn't have been deployable either.

Comment: @Schneems I was able to duplicate with acts_as_taggable. without the `acts_as_taggable` on a new rails4 app, it attempts to create in asset precompile.

Comment: I can confirm that this solves the problem. More info about it here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/192